# how to use loop in stored procedure to copy data from one table to another in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on SQL Server. I have a table `Trans_Details` with these columns:

```
empId    transDateTime   Created_Date    LeaveStatus
```

I have another table `Trans_Leave`:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER    NAME          DATE_START      DATE_END 
 1                 annual leav     2015-06-01    2015-06-10
```

I want to write a stored procedure to insert values from the `Trans_Leave` table into the `Trans_Details` table.

first i want to check weather that employee number exist in the `Trans_Details` table .if exist i want to update particular employee number other wise i want to insert that records to `Trans_Details` table

In a stored procedure I want to use a loop to insert record from **2015-06-10 
to 2015-06-10**

My expected result looks like this:

```
empId  transDateTime Created_Date  LeavStatus
1       2015-06-01    currentdate   annual leav
1       2015-06-02    ""             annual leav
1       2015-06-03        ""          annual leav
1       2015-06-04        ""          annual leav
--        ----           ---             ---
1        2015-06-10      ""             annual leav
```

any help is very appreciable..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert ... select` to copy rows without a loop.  I've added the statements for an "upsert" as requested in your comment.

```
insert  Trans_Details
        (empId, transDateTime, Created_date, LeaveStatus)
select  employee_number
,       date_start
,       getdate()
,       name
from    Trans_Leave tl
where   start_date between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-10'
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Trans_Details td
        where   transDateTime between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-10'
                and tl.employee_number = td.empId
        )

update  td
set     transDateTime = date_start
,       Created_date = now()
,       LeaveStatus = name
from    Trans_Details td
join    Trans_Leave tl
on      tl.employee_number = td.empId
where   transDateTime between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-10'
        and date_start between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-10'
```

Comment: sir...first i want to check whethar that empId is already existing in Trans_details table within that date,,if existing then i want to update particular data.if not exist then only i want to inseart

Comment: sir i want to ask one thing..while inserting this query will insert date from 2015-06-01 to 2015-06-10(this time i want to insert 10 records)

Comment: Wouldn't recommend running queries from the internet without verifying them yourself. Make a copy of the tables and have a go.

Comment: i have small query like this:
declare currentDate datetime,enddate datetime;

select currentDate = '06/1/2015';
select enddate='06/05/2015'
while  currentDate <= enddate

begin

-- do whatever is needed

select currentDate = dateadd(DAY,1,currentDate);
select currentDate as currentdate
end
in this result not getting currentdate

Comment: sir your query is wrong..it s not insearting all dates records..only inserting first date

Answer (score 0):

To be able to easily populate a range of dates, you should create a table that contains all the possible days you'll ever need (e.g. 1.1.2010 - 31.12.2099), one date per row. With that table this is easy to solve.

Assuming you create table with name DATES and column CALENDARDATE is the date, you can just join it with your data, something like this:

```
insert into XXX
select
  L.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
  L.NAME,
  D.CALENDARDATE
from
  DATES D
  Trans_Leave L   
where
  D.CALENDARDATE >= L.DATE_START and
  D.CALENDARDATE <= L.DATE_END
```

Comment: i didnt get..can u able to do with my table Please

Comment: That was your table, I just added one new table called DATES, since that helps you a lot. Then you don't have to add loops or anything like that