# using while loop not looping through date properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

i have query like this :

```
declare @currentDate datetime,@enddate datetime;

set @currentDate = '06/1/2015';
select @enddate='06/05/2015'

while @currentDate < @enddate



begin



select @currentDate = dateadd(DAY,1,@currentDate);
select @currentDate as currentdate
end
```

**but in the result set this is not showing my current date**.it s showing date from 2015-06-02 on wards..i want to include my current date also

Comment: i am getting only 4 records. from 2015-02-06 to 2015-05-06.actually i want to get 5 records.from 2015-01-06 to 2015-05-06

Comment: Please use YYYYMMDD format, others have different meanings depending on language / locale settings. If you want the first day to be shown, do the select before change the value, and change the end condition to be <= @enddate

Comment: dear @JamesZ ,,can u able to show your sample code? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant:

```
declare @currentDate datetime,@enddate datetime

set @currentDate = '20150601'
set @enddate='20150605'

while (@currentDate <= @enddate) begin
  select @currentDate as currentdate
  select @currentDate = dateadd(DAY,1,@currentDate)
end
```

Comment: sir this is worked..actually i want to achieve this:can u please look on this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962125/how-to-use-loop-in-stored-procedure-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-sq

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in the while loop is increment currentDate. This will move it from 06/1/2015 to 06/2/2015 straight away so instead do:

```
declare @currentDate datetime,@enddate datetime;
set @currentDate = '06/1/2015';
select @enddate='06/05/2015'
while @currentDate < @enddate --- May need to be <= if inclusive range.
begin    
    --- Do stuff with currentDate here THEN increment at the very end.
    set @currentDate = dateadd(DAY,1,@currentDate);
end
```

Comment: so in this case what i want to change?

Comment: or i can use any other ideas?

Comment: The last thing in the while loop has to be the increment. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/05177b42-871b-4620-ad76-3ee5a683cd22/while-loop-for-date shows examples shows examples

Comment: sir can u please look on this link:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962125/how-to-use-loop-in-stored-procedure-to-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-in-sq

Comment: actually i want to achieve this..i am struggling with that